# Can't access class' parent's companion object

Tags: kotlin

In my class I'm referencing a utils object that holds some consts. That utils object inherits from a parent utils object that also has consts. In my class, I want to access the parent's companion consts via a reference to the child utils class. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

This isn't technically necessary (simply referencing the base class works in my specific case) but I'm still interested from a language perspective if this is possible.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. You start by talking about objects, then objects become classes. Everything would be s much easier to understand if you simply posted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#companion-objects) and their members can only be accessed via the containing class name, not via instances of the containing class. *[...]* If you try to redeclare a companion object in a subclass, you'll just shadow the one from the base class.

In other words: It's not possible, as both companion objects are completely unrelated.